# EACCES error when creating a folder

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano, rack, file-permissions

I'm a Linux and Ruby noob, so please bear with me.

I'm writing a small Ruby app using Sinatra, and deploy it using Capistrano to a Linux server. I was able to successfully run the app no problem locally, or even remotely using `rack -p 4567`.

My app creates a directory (let's call it `/foo`) using `Dir::mkdir`, and sub-directories and files inside this `/foo` directory. When I execute the rack using the daemon -D option, I suddenly get file permission error when creating the `/foo` folder.

```
rackup -D -p 4567
```

I know this has something to do with file permissions, but I am not sure what to set here. The web recommends chmod, but that's if you are running from shell, right? I have tried passing `0700` or `0777` to `Dir::mkdir` but they didn't seem to help. How can I give daemon permissions to create directories and files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is because I didn't use absolute paths in my app. So the current working directory is pointing to the /usr/bin where ruby is located.

Use `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` to get the path where your script is.